# Dont allow repeat two commas two dots regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to forbiden to write more that one dot, as well i want to forbiden to write more that one comma

if there is already an dot (.) should not allow to write other dot(.) or comma (,) and viceversa

i have this example:

```js
function isNumberKey(evt, obj) {
  if (evt.target.selectionStart === 0 && (evt.keyCode == 46)) return false;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
  var value = obj.value;
  var dotcontains = value.indexOf(".") != -1;
  var commacontains = value.indexOf(",") != -1;
  if ((value.length == 0) && (event.keyCode == 46)) return false
  if (dotcontains || commacontains)
    if (charCode == 46 || charCode == 44) return false;

  if (charCode == 46 || charCode == 44) return true;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

```html
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)">
```

that is working but i need to do that with regex

i was trying with this regex:

```
/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*$/
```

it should work like

```html
<input type="number" />
```

Comment: if it's working, why do you need to switch to regex? Have you made any attempt to do this yourself at all?

Comment: Why would you want to validate numeric input yourself instead of using `<input type="number">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this regex

```
[^\d.,]|(^\d*[.,]\d*).*
```

and replace it with `$1`.

Basically it only allows numeric characters, `,` and `.`, and it only allows one `,` or `.` to be present, anything other than those will be replaced to empty on the fly.

---

### Edit

According to the added information in comments, to only allow maximum 3 fraction digits, you may change the regex a little bit:

```
[^\d.,]|(^\d*[.,]\d{0,3}).*
```

---

### Edit 2

To allow numbers only lower than 1 million, you can restrict the maximum significant digits to 6, and make the fraction part optional:

```
[^\d.,]|(^\d{0,6}(?:[.,]\d{0,3})?).*
```

```js
const $input = document.querySelector('input');

$input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  $input.value = $input.value.replace(/[^\d.,]|(^\d{0,6}(?:[.,]\d{0,3})?).*/g, '$1');
});
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: @InforMation Do you mean maximum fraction digits? You may check the updated answer.

Comment: @InforMation Please check the updated answer again. If you have more things to add ,please edit your question instead of commenting here.

Comment: but this does not worked when i passe with new Regexp like this  new RegExp(`[^\d.,]|(^\d*[.,]\d{0,3}).*`)